# Select tables data with sum of other tables

Tags: mysql, join

I am very new on MySQL DBA and i searched but i am not clearly understanding inner join with sum.

```
user table:

id, username, locationid

history table:

id, username, locationid, spent


Example user table:

1, sarah12, 12
2, martin21, 12
3, sarah12, 13


Example history table:

1, sarah12, 12, 100
2, martin21, 12, 40
3, sarah12, 13, 500
4, sarah12, 12, 50
```

Now i want to list all users with sum of their spending history by specific location ID.

Like i want to list all users which has locationid 12 with sum of their spending history

So, i am expecting something like that:

```
1, sarah12, 150
2, martin21, 40
```

Can you please guide me how can i do that?

Edit:
Basically i try with random solution from stackoverflow. I have added my last tried code. But it seems it does not work.
Here is the last one:

```
select user.*, history.spent as intotal
from user
  inner join (select username, sum(spent) as total from history group by username) history on 
  user.username = history.username
where user.locationid = 12
```

Comment: Please post your query so far to show that you have tried.

Comment: You seem to be aware of the `join` operation; have you tried using it?

Comment: @RohitGupta Hello, basically i tried with random solution from from stackoverflow. I have added my last tried code

Comment: @mustaccio Hello, basically i tried with random solution from from stackoverflow. I have added my last tried code

Answer (score 0):

Think through it this way it will be executed:

1. `JOIN` the `user` and `history` tables together.  Imagine the resulting "table" that contains all combinations of rows -- based on `ON`, which controls how the tables are related.
2. Filter out unwanted rows by saying which ones to keep: `WHERE user.locationid = 12`.
3. Now perform the `GROUP BY user_id` and compute the aggregate `SUM(history.spent)`.  Note that this step happens *after* combining the tables.  It is 'correct' for your query, but could be incorrect in some other situations.

   SELECT  user.username,
   SUM(history.spent) AS tot_spent
   FROM user
   JOIN history  ON history.user_id = user.id
   GROUP BY user.id

Note that `username` should not be replicated in `history`, instead it should be accessed in the other table via the id.

I like to use short aliases rather than clutter the query with long table names:

```
  SELECT  u.username,
          SUM(h.spent) AS tot_spent
      FROM user AS u
      JOIN history AS h  ON h.user_id = u.id
      GROUP BY u.id
```

(The database engine's Optimizer may have shortcuts to the 3 steps I listed above.  But it is guaranteed to get the same answer, hopefully faster.)

You proposed a "derived table" -- `FROM ( SELECT ... ) AS x`.  This is *sometimes* the "right" way to a task.  The prime case is when the `GROUP BY` needs to be done in the derived table *before* inflating the combined tables.  Your attempt has multiple problems:

```
 SELECT ... history.spent   -- Can't seen inside the subquery
     FROM ( SELECT ... FROM history ...
          )    -- An alias is _required_ here
     ...
     WHERE ...   -- I think you want this filtering to happen before SUMming
```

A third way is with a subquery:

```
SELECT u.username,
       ( SELECT SUM(h.spent) FROM history AS h
             WHERE h.user_id = u.id     -- reaching outside for u.id
               AND h.location_id = 12   -- filtering is here
       ) AS total
    FROM user AS u;
```

In *some* cases, this approach will be faster.  It *may* actually be clearer for your use case.